# Getting a consensus sequence per species from a fasta with sequences from many species in R

Tags: r, bioconductor, dna-sequence, genetics

In R, I have a fasta (ex: Andrenidae.FASTA) with a few hundred nucleotide sequences from a dozen species. I want to get 1 consensus sequence for each species. Each sequence is made up of A/C/T/G/N, with N representing unknown nucleotides, and the sequence names are species names. All sequences are the exact same length, and I've already aligned them.

The issue is that I want the most common nucleotide at each position to be picked for the consensus sequences, and I want any of A/C/T/G to override N. So N should only be picked for the consensus if every sequence for that species contains N at that position. If even 1 sequence has an A/C/T/G, whichever one is most common goes into the consensus rather than N. This is because these aligned sequences come from several longer sequences of different parts of this gene, so often some parts of the gene were only sequenced for a small number of these sequences.

Currently, this R code treats A/C/T/G/N equally, so I end up with way too many N in my consensus sequences:

```r
library(Biostrings) 

seqs <- readDNAStringSet("Andrenidae.FASTA")
species_names <- sapply(names(seqs), function(x) strsplit(x, " ")[[1]][1])
species_sequences <- split(seqs, species_names)

#get the species names in a vector
sp<- unique(species_names)
#create empty list to fill with consensus sequences
con_seq <- list()

#calculate consensus sequences
for(i in 1:10){
  con_seq[[i]] <- consensusString(species_sequences[[i]], ambiguityMap="N", 
                                  threshold=0.0001)
}

#unlist con seq into one large vector
cs_all<-unlist(con_seq)
#create a dataframe with the species names and their corresponding con seq
cs_all_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(sp, cs_all))
#write out df
write.csv(cs_all_df, file='Andrenidae_con.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `ambiguityMap` and `thresholdd` from the function.
Setting `ambiguityMap = N` and `thresholdd = .0001` means that sequences containing a nucleotide that occurs less frequently than 0.01% of the time in the input set will be replaced with `N` in consensus calculation.

Here is a little working example:

```
# 3 Ns and one A at 3rd pos
consensusString(DNAStringSet(c("ACNG","ACNR", "ACNG", "ACAG")))
# output:
# "ACAG"

# all Ns 
consensusString(DNAStringSet(c("ACNG","ACNR", "ACNG", "ACNG")))
# output:
#"ACNG"

# with those parameters set
consensusString(DNAStringSet(c("ACNG","ACNR", "ACNG", "ACAG")), ambiguityMap = "N", threshold = 0.001)
# output
#  "ACNN"
```